# no error reporting no matter what i try

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How do I enable error reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting)

yesterday i had this question:
[nothing show's up when class is in php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731847/nothing-shows-up-when-class-is-in-php-code#comment17196650_12731847)

Normally i work on my own host but now i switched and i didn't realize i had error reporting off. Now i try to get it on.
I don't have acces to the root so i created my own ini.php, does that matter?
In ini.php i tried:

```
php_flag    display_errors          on
php_flag    display_startup_errors  on
php_value   error_reporting         2047
```

But no errors show up, and neither does the website..
Then i tried .htaccess which is alowed to be in every folder if i recall corect.

.htaccess has:

```
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

But no errors and no website again.

also tried .htacces with:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  display_errors 1
</IfModule>
```

which gives:

> The script could not be executed correctly. Common causes might be
>   that the file was uploaded in a non-ASCII format or the path to the
>   interpreter (e.g.: #!/usr/bin/perl) is missing or set incorrectly.

I tried then just as php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(64);
require('test.txt');
?>
```

which shows no error 
Also tried:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

and still no errors and no website :(

Does anyone have a idea what i can do? :(

Comment: Try to put the code from the Accepted Answer into your bootstrap. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: where you think i got all the above info from?
Only none of them helped.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
```

even though this has been asked so many times...

Comment: If it's been asked so many times, post the duplicate and don't answer.

Comment: I am searching like crazy for a page (community wiki perhaps) i've seen once which was all about PHP and also mentioned the possible debugging methods.. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Ah, there we go: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the manual [http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

```
error_reporting NULL    PHP_INI_ALL
display_errors  "1" PHP_INI_ALL
```

To Test it just try this:

```
<?php
  ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  echo $notExistingVar;
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: I looked in phpinfo andit says php.ini should be here: `/etc/php5.3/php.ini`. However i can't find that folder.

Comment: >>However i can't find that folder. when you don't have root access to the server it doesn't matter, that you can't see this folder ... but phpinfo() gives you a table (under Core) with to ini Values (Local Value Master Value) and the setting that takes actually effect is the Local Value  .... so take a look at the output for the Directives error_reporting and display_errors and which Value is set ...

Comment: ok: `error_reporting 337 30711` and `display_errors Off On`